# Swift: TCP socket keep-alive

Tags: ios, sockets, tcp, swift

I'm developing an iOS app (using Swift) which uses a TCP connection to a TCP server. Currently, whenever I've sent something, the connection closes automatically. I want to keep the connection open/alive until I manually close it.

From [this Objective-C-based question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785917/nsstream-tcp-keep-alive-ios) I found that it could be done like this in Objective-C:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
...
CFDataRef socketData = CFReadStreamCopyProperty((__bridge CFReadStreamRef)(stream), kCFStreamPropertySocketNativeHandle);
CFSocketNativeHandle socket;
CFDataGetBytes(socketData, CFRangeMake(0, sizeof(CFSocketNativeHandle)), (UInt8 *)&socket);
CFRelease(socketData);

int on = 1;
if (setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &on, sizeof(on)) == -1) {
    NSLog(@"setsockopt failed: %s", strerror(errno));
}
```

My current Swift implementation/translation looks like this:

```
var socketData = CFReadStreamCopyProperty(inputStream, kCFStreamPropertySocketNativeHandle) as CFDataRef
var socket: CFSocketNativeHandle
CFDataGetBytes(socketData, CFRangeMake(0, sizeof(CFSocketNativeHandle)), (UInt8).self&socket)

var on: UInt8 = 1;
if setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &on, 255) == -1 {
}
```

A few notes:

- `inputStream` is declared as: `var inputStream: NSInputStream?`
- I'm not sure if using `255` as an alternative to `sizeof(on)` is a good idea.
- The code happens in the function `func stream(theStream:NSStream, handleEvent streamEvent:NSStreamEvent)` which is required by using the `NSStreamDelegate` protocol.
- I'm not sure if using `inputStream` instead of `theStream` (function parameter) is a good idea.

I'm getting an Xcode error on the `CFDataGetBytes` function. It says the following:

> 'NSData' is not a subtype of of 'CFData'

Any idea how to fix that?

Also, how do I import/include `<sys/socket.h>` in my Swift file? I've seen something called bridging headers, but isn't that only for Obj-C side-by-side with Swift implementations?

Comment: TCP keep-alive is to detect errors on idle connections. It does not help against "automatic closing". The latter is an application problem and to help here one would need to see your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CFDataRef` is "toll-free bridged" to `NSData`, therefore the first part can be
more simply written as

```
var socketData = CFReadStreamCopyProperty(inputStream, kCFStreamPropertySocketNativeHandle) as NSData
var socket: CFSocketNativeHandle = 0
socketData.getBytes(&socket, length: sizeofValue(socket))
```

The "option_value" argument of `setsockopt()` is the address of an `int` (which is mapped to Swift as `UInt32`), and the last argument has to be the size of that variable:

```
var on: UInt32 = 1;
if setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &on, socklen_t(sizeofValue(on))) == -1 {
    let errmsg = String.fromCString(strerror(errno))
    println("setsockopt failed: \(errno) \(errmsg)")
}
```

`<sys/socket.h>` is imported by default.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you happen to know where to look if I get `setsockopt failed: 0x00007ff369887200`? That is, the `setsockopt` function returns -1.

Comment: @eightx2: I have updated the code to show a proper error number and message in the failure case. - The possible errnos are listed in the man pages ("man setsockopt" in the Terminal, or https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/setsockopt.2.html).

Comment: @eightx2: Did you make any progress?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I got this error: `setsockopt failed: 22 Invalid argument`. I learned that I had to just write `8` instead of `socklen_t(sizeofValue(on))`.

Comment: @eightx2: That means that `UInt8` is not the right data type for the socket option. The C `int` maps to `Int32`, so you probably have to use `var on: UInt32 = 1` (together with `socklen_t(sizeofValue(on))`).