# How to keep socket open on iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, sockets

I have an iOS app in which I communicate with a wifi chip acting as a TCP server.  The problem is that the socket (shuts down?) after 3 minutes, 45 seconds of being idle.  I've heard about keepalive signals and from my research, it seems like I should be able to use something like setsockopt to keep the connection open.  I just can't get it working correctly.

Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
    var outputStream: NSOutputStream!

    var readStream: Unmanaged<CFReadStreamRef>?
    var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStreamRef>?

    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(nil,serverAddress, serverPort, &readStream, &writeStream)
    inputStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()   // ???
    outputStream = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue()

    inputStream.open()
    outputStream.open()
    outputCommandQueue = OutgoingCommandQueue(Stream: outputStream)

    var optval: Int = 1; // Use 1 to enable the option, 0 to disable
    let socketData = CFWriteStreamCopyProperty(outputStream, kCFStreamPropertySocketNativeHandle) as! Int32 // Get a reference to the socket itself.
    setsockopt(socketData, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &optval, socklen_t(sizeof(Int)))  // setsockopt(ref of socket, at socket level, option to keepalive, set equal to one (on), something about the length of the variable)
```

I added the last three lines of code to keep my connection alive, and this compiles fine but I get an "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error on the

```
let socketData = ...
```

line.

Obviously my CFWriteStreamCopyProperty line is not returning a value (or returning a nil value), but that just leaves me at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong.  Would greatly appreciate any assistance/pointers as to what I'm doing wrong, or if I'm just using the wrong approach here.

Question is pretty similar to [Swift: TCP socket keep-alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632257/swift-tcp-socket-keep-alive)
but I'm not sure that will work with my code (or how I would even implement it in my code).  I am more of an advanced beginner than an advanced developer, so answers in simple terms are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't done much socket programming, so I might be way off base here. The docs say `kCFStreamPropertySocketNativeHandle`'s value is a `CFData` object (the headers return `AnyObject!`), so I don't think `as! Int32` will ever succeed. You might want to get rid of the cast (or move it to a separate `if let` statement) while you're debugging.

Comment: Also, this looks impossible from your code snippet, but double-check that `outputStream` isn't `nil` (that is also an implicitly unwrapped optional, so could cause the same error message)