# Proxy server persistent connection closing

Tags: objective-c, proxy, osx-yosemite, nsstream, nsurlprotocol

I'm implementing proxy support for an osx app.

I've created a custom `NSURLProtocol` and it is working perfectly for a proxy without authentication. Tried with both CCProxy and FreeProxy on a Windows computer in the local network.

However when proxy authentication is on, any request in the first few seconds works perfectly then the connection goes from ESTABLISHED to CLOSE_WAIT in 5 seconds. The proxy shows 0 connections again and, after that in the app any HTTP request will get a 407, even though the proxy-auth header is pre-set.

My code looks like this :

```
// set the auth fields
CFStringRef usernameRef = (__bridge CFStringRef)appProxyPrefs.proxyUserName;
CFStringRef passwordRef = (__bridge CFStringRef)appProxyPrefs.proxyPassword;
CFHTTPMessageAddAuthentication(copyOfOriginal, nil, usernameRef, passwordRef, kCFHTTPAuthenticationSchemeBasic, YES);
...
// useless
CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue(copyOfOriginal, (__bridge CFStringRef)@"Connection", (CFStringRef)(@"Keep-Alive"));
... 
// create stream, callback, schedule
// apply proxy settings to the stream
if (isNoProxyOverride)
    CFReadStreamSetProperty(myReadStream, kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxy, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(noProxyDict));
else
    CFReadStreamSetProperty(myReadStream, kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxy, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(manualProxyDict));
...
CFReadStreamSetProperty(myReadStream, kCFStreamPropertyHTTPAttemptPersistentConnection, kCFBooleanTrue);
if (!CFReadStreamOpen(myReadStream)) {  // error }      
    else
    {
        // check if there is a prev stream
        if (currentStream != nil)
        {
            [currentStream close];
            currentStream = nil;
        }
        currentStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)(myReadStream);
    }
```

As you see I tried to store the previous conenction in a static inputstream and releasing it only after I open a new one, but seems useless.

Also tried setting the underlying socket to keep-alive in `kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted` as suggested in [NSStream TCP Keep-alive iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785917/nsstream-tcp-keep-alive-ios) , still without success.

Why does the connection close ? How could I debug it or make it work ?
Is the connection's fault the proxy goes craxy ?

Thanks.

**Edit 1**: [image: wireshark]

**Edit 2**: It seems it has to do with HTTPS... If I change the the server to be plain http instead of https it will work perfectly.

Comment: Did you check with a traffic capture what side sends the FIN packet? This would narrow it down to a client vs. proxy problem.

Comment: @RomanK Installed wireshark on the windows machine and the connection seems to be "live", then the proxy ? sends a FIN and the connection is kept-alive. See edit.

Comment: It's hard to see from the capture whether 192.168.1.141 is the proxy or the client, but let's assume it's the proxy.

There is also a preceding TLS alert, so it's definitely TLS-related as you suspect.
It's worth looking at the details of the alert packet and/or proxy logs as they might give a hint.
Also, how do you do authentication with a proxy - do you send the `Proxy-Authorization: Basic` header on the initial CONNECT?

Comment: 141 is the proxy at port 5555. The 3rd line adds the proxy-auth header. Currently, when I get a 407 I'll just resend the same request and it will get authenticated, I don't really know why wouldn't work with the headers added preemptively when using HTTPS ...

Comment: So just to reiterate my question - do you add the preemptive `Proxy-Authorization` on CONNECT? It's hard to see from just the packet titles.

Comment: @RomanK Yes, every time.