# Timeout for NSURLRequest in ios7

Tags: ios, ios7, nsurlconnection, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I am using api in my app. The server has a api which will send response when there is any specific change. For that I have to let a connection always open. Is there any problem if I do so? Another question can I make other request to same server while there is a connect open??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387560/keeping-a-socket-connection-alive-in-ios